# MongoDB select and concatenate fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a very basic question:

```
SELECT name, surname CONCAT(name, surname) AS name_surname from users;
```

How can I convert this `SQL` to `MongoDB` query?

During my search, I have decided that it is possible with aggregate framework due to `concat`, but what I received is only `projection` of `concat(name, surname)` not `name`, `surname` and `concat(name, surname)`.

Final thing I got is this query:

```
db.inroamers.find().forEach(
                 function(o) { 
                 print(o.LAC + '-' + o.CELL + ' ' + o.CHARGE + ' ' + o.WEEK);
               })
```

but it does not give me proper `json` array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the aggregation operations as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project:{"name_surname":{$concat:["$name","-","$surname"]},"name":1,"surname":1}}
])
```