# merge two different field in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, merge, field

I want to merge two different field in a mongoose 
in sql i can do something like this

```
select (first-name last-name) as fullname from person_tbl
```

this would produce something like this

```
First name  Last name       Fullname
Smith       Bryan           Smith Bryan
Joseph      Grant           Joseph  Grant
Diana       Blake           Diana Blake
```

How can I do that in the mongooose
I am very confused as to how to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB select and concatenate fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035340/mongodb-select-and-concatenate-fields)

Answer (score 2):

In mongoose, use aggregation to achieve concatenation of values of two keys. Let's say, we have a `Person` model in the mongoose and `firstName`, `lastName` are two fields in the document, to get the `fullName`:

```
Person.aggregate([
    {$project: {fullName: {$concat: ["$firstName", " ", "$lastName"]}}}
  ]);
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b83d435c671fcae13004e0f"), "fullName" : "Shivam Pandey" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b83d459c671fcae13004e10"), "fullName" : "J. Whit" }
```

MongoDB Ref: [Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/)

Comment: I my mongoose I have something like this Person.find({_id:'some field for the search'}).select(' field1 field2 field3'). Using your above, would it not be like this Person.find({_id:'some field for the search'}).select(' field1 field2 field3').aggregate([
    {$project: {fullName: {$concat: ["$firstName", " ", "$lastName"]}}}
  ]);. is this going to affect the speed of the server in anyway

Comment: **@Shivam Pandey** Thanks for the response but it did not work with mongoose maybe it might with mongodb but not with mongoose

Comment: @J.Whit I tested it on mongo console. Ok, Let me test it for a mongoose schema.